# AES encryption in Perl with custom Key and IV

Tags: javascript, perl, encryption, aes

I have the following AES encryption code in JavaScript, but I can't seem to get comparable result in Perl.

```js
'use strict';
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const message = 's3cret';
const aesPassword = 'MyPassword';
const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(aesPassword, salt, {keySize: 128/32, iterations: 1000});
const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {iv: iv}).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
const encryptedMessage = Buffer.from(iv + '::' + salt + '::' + ciphertext).toString('base64');
console.log("encryptedMessage:", encryptedMessage);
```

```
encryptedMessage: NDNjOWNjYmE2MzBmZTFjZDYxZmMyYmRiOTAxMjFjNmY6OjVjNzg4YTQxNTg1MWU5MDlkOWM3OTUxNzE3NzE0MjA0OjpxVDFWdG9kN2loUzJ3dnR3bWxuUG93PT0=
```

(92 bytes before base64 encoding.)

Perl:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::CBC;
use Crypt::PBKDF2;
use MIME::Base64;

my $message = 's3cret';
my $aesPassword = 'MyPassword';
my $salt = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes(16);
my $iv = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes(16);
my $pbkdf2 = Crypt::PBKDF2->new(output_len=>128/32, iterations => 1000);
my $key = $pbkdf2->PBKDF2($aesPassword, $salt);
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-cipher=>'Cipher::AES', -pbkdf=>'pbkdf2', -key=>$key, -iv=>$iv, -header=>'none');
my $ciphertext = encode_base64( $cipher->encrypt($message), "" );
my $encryptedMessage = encode_base64( join('::', $iv, $salt, $ciphertext), "" );
print "encryptedMessage: $encryptedMessage";
```

```
encryptedMessage: tO/jlJ3NkuJG0ZA58EDR0Do6wUf4xHb/MwWm3iyT+ejYWDo6SllMSHB0S0ZuMDVYWDRzS3ZCWlRiZz09Cg==
```

(61 bytes before base64 encoding.)

Comment: Nope, [crypto.se] is the wrong Q/A site (SE doesn't do "forums", "communities" maybe); migrated the question to [so]. Please include the output so we don't have to compile, run... Indicate what you are expecting (other than different randomized bytes, I mean `random_bytes` for the salt & IV should give a hint).

Comment: You used different IVs, so you *should* get something different.   ...except they should be the same length.

Comment: If you pass an empty string as `encode_base64` second argument, it doesn't add line breaks. I've adjusted the code.

Comment: `-pbkdf=>'pbkdf2'` is fishy, seeing as you already used PBKDF2

Comment: You're not hex encoding the key and IV, which is performed implicitly by the string concatenation in JS (note: encoding should happen *after* you've used them for the cipher). Furthermore, you should not need the `-pbkdf` parameter for the CBC encryption. Those are the most obvious issues, there may be more.

Comment: Double encoding to text is always a bad idea. So is relying on implicit encoding rules as those may change (and can remain hidden to readers of the code, as we find out here). Quite often it is not even necessary to convert the ciphertext to string *at all*. If you'd have looked at the intermediate result you'd immediately have spotted the problem, so use a debugger / print statement for intermediate results before asking here.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes -Using `-pbkdf => 'none'` complains about the key length not being 32. So there's a bit more to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `encode_base64( ..., "" )` to avoid the addition of line breaks and a trailing LF. (Already fixed in the OP.)
- You have the order of the arguments of the call to `->PBKDF2` backwards.
- You ask Crypt::CBC to use PBKDF2 despite already having already applied it. `-pbkdf => 'none'` should be used.
- You generate a key of the wrong length. 128/32 should be 128/8.
- You need to tell Crypt::CBC when using a key length that isn't the largest possible. `-keysize => length( $key )` should be used.
- You are storing the hex of the IV and salt in the JS version, but the raw IV and salt in the Perl version.

[Thanks to @Topaco for identifying most of these.]

Fixed version:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Crypt::CBC    qw( );
use Crypt::PBKDF2 qw( );
use MIME::Base64  qw( encode_base64 );

use constant KEY_SIZE => 128 / 8;

my $plaintext = 's3cret';
my $password  = 'MyPassword';

#my $iv   = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes( 16 );
#my $salt = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes( 16 );
my $iv   = pack( "H*", "43c9ccba630fe1cd61fc2bdb90121c6f" );  # For testing.
my $salt = pack( "H*", "5c788a415851e909d9c7951717714204" );  # For testing.

my $pbkdf2 = Crypt::PBKDF2->new(
   output_len => KEY_SIZE,
   iterations => 1000,
);

my $key = $pbkdf2->PBKDF2( $salt, $password );

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
   -cipher  => 'Cipher::AES',
   -header  => 'none',
   -pbkdf   => 'none',
   -keysize => KEY_SIZE,
   -key     => $key,
   -iv      => $iv,
);

my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt( $plaintext );

my $ciphertext_base64 = encode_base64( $ciphertext, "" );
my $iv_hex   = unpack( "H*", $iv );
my $salt_hex = unpack( "H*", $salt );

my $msg = join( '::', $iv_hex, $salt_hex, $ciphertext_base64 );
my $msg_base64 = encode_base64( $msg, "" );

say $msg;
say length( $msg );
say $msg_base64;
```

```
43c9ccba630fe1cd61fc2bdb90121c6f::5c788a415851e909d9c7951717714204::qT1Vtod7ihS2wvtwmlnPow==
92
NDNjOWNjYmE2MzBmZTFjZDYxZmMyYmRiOTAxMjFjNmY6OjVjNzg4YTQxNTg1MWU5MDlkOWM3OTUxNzE3NzE0MjA0OjpxVDFWdG9kN2loUzJ3dnR3bWxuUG93PT0=
```

Comment: Ah, you already found out about `output_len` :) You've still got `-pbkdf` though

Comment: Uh, and you divide by 32, shouldn't that be 8? It's in bytes, not words.

Comment: Oh, it **is** in words in the JavaScript code, but not in the Perl code (so you do need `/ 8`). Both libraries are so badly coded / documented that I give up. Hope you can help the OP to get it right. Don't use scripting languages for any real security related tasks, they are horrible at it. For encryption you get `ciphertext = magic(input, params), plaintext = unmagic(ciphertext, params) `

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, The divide by 32 is from the OP's code. And 128/8 is 16. Crypt::CBC requires a 32-bit key.

Comment: In CryptoJS the key size is specified in words (1 word = 4 bytes): 128/32 words = 4 words = 16 bytes = 128/8 bytes. Therefore it must be specified in the Perl script: `output_len=>128/8`.

Comment: Another bug is the double key derivation. Since the key has already been explicitly derived, the implicit key derivation must be disabled with `-pbkdf=>'none'`. The resulting key size complaint is due to the fact that by default a 32 bytes key is required, but you are using a 16 bytes key. For this reason you must additionally specify `-keysize=>16`. Note that `-header=>'none'` is not necessary since implicit key derivation is disabled. BTW, implicit key derivation would not be possible here at all, because this requires a mandatory 8 bytes salt (and the user applies a 16 bytes salt).

Comment: Another issue is that the arguments in the PBKDF2 call are swapped. Correct is: `my $key = $pbkdf2->PBKDF2($salt, $aesPassword)`. With these changes, both codes return the same result (for identical salt and IV).

Comment: Answer updated to fully answer the question, thanks to the info from @Topaco.

Comment: Dangit, I didn't check the parameters as I thought that would be unlikely to be missed by anybody checking the code, probably the one that I was still missing.

Comment: Thank you ikegami, @MaartenBodewes, Topaco
Just tested, it works as expected.