# AES encryption in Perl similar to crypto-js@4.2.0

Tags: javascript, perl, encryption, aes, cryptojs

The following JavaScript code:

```js
'use strict';
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const plaintext = 's3cret';
const password  = 'MyPassword';
//const iv   = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
//const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
const iv   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("43c9ccba630fe1cd61fc2bdb90121c6f"); // For testing
const salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("5c788a415851e909d9c7951717714204"); // For testing
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {keySize: 128/32, iterations: 1000});
const b64ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {iv: iv}).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log(b64ciphertext);
```

1. Using [`crypto-js@4.2.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js/v/4.2.0), produces:

   ```js
   'use strict';

   const plaintext = 's3cret';
   const password = 'MyPassword';
   //const iv   = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
   //const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
   const iv   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("43c9ccba630fe1cd61fc2bdb90121c6f"); // For testing
   const salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("5c788a415851e909d9c7951717714204"); // For testing
   const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {keySize: 128/32, iterations: 1000});
   console.log("key: " + key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
   const b64ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {iv: iv}).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
   console.log("ciphertext: " + b64ciphertext);
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.2.0/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha512-a+SUDuwNzXDvz4XrIcXHuCf089/iJAoN4lmrXJg18XnduKK6YlDHNRalv4yd1N40OKI80tFidF+rqTFKGPoWFQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
   ```

```
key: 8E2dqz889iLAam1MV4wweQ==
ciphertext: eiJkaAmCVjHFKbvY/CnkvQ==
```

2. Using [`crypto-js@4.1.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js/v/4.1.1), produces:

   ```js
   'use strict';

   const plaintext = 's3cret';
   const password = 'MyPassword';
   //const iv   = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
   //const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
   const iv   = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("43c9ccba630fe1cd61fc2bdb90121c6f"); // For testing
   const salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("5c788a415851e909d9c7951717714204"); // For testing
   const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {keySize: 128/32, iterations: 1000});
   console.log("key: " + key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
   const b64ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {iv: iv}).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
   console.log("ciphertext: " + b64ciphertext);
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha512-E8QSvWZ0eCLGk4km3hxSsNmGWbLtSCSUcewDQPQWZF6pEU8GlT8a5fF32wOl1i8ftdMhssTrF/OhyGWwonTcXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
   ```

```
key: 8NJim/oe3/Q0+wLRq86FGg==
ciphertext: qT1Vtod7ihS2wvtwmlnPow==
```

The Perl equivalent for the `crypto-js@4.1.1` output was provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76847270/2035207):

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Crypt::CBC    qw( );
use Crypt::PBKDF2 qw( );
use Mojo::Util qw(b64_encode);

my $plaintext = 's3cret';
my $password  = 'MyPassword';
#my $iv   = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes( 16 );
#my $salt = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes( 16 );
my $iv   = pack( "H*", "43c9ccba630fe1cd61fc2bdb90121c6f" ); # For testing
my $salt = pack( "H*", "5c788a415851e909d9c7951717714204" ); # For testing

my $pbkdf2 = Crypt::PBKDF2->new(output_len=>128/8, iterations=>1000);
my $key = $pbkdf2->PBKDF2($salt,$password);
say "key: ", b64_encode($key,'');
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
                 -cipher  => 'Cipher::AES',
                 -header  => 'none',
                 -pbkdf   => 'none',
                 -keysize => length($key),
                 -key     => $key,
                 -iv      => $iv
                );
my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt( $plaintext );
my $b64ciphertext = b64_encode($ciphertext,'');

say "ciphertext: ", $b64ciphertext;
```

Using Perl, how can I get an output similar to `crypto-js@4.2.0`?

Comment: 4.2.0: "Change default hash algorithm and iteration's for PBKDF2 to prevent weak security by using the default configuration.", "Custom KDF Hasher", "Blowfish support" /// So they changed the default config of PBKDF2. So what is that config? (And ideally, what was it before?)

Comment: [The change](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/commit/421dd538b2d34e7c24a5b72cc64dc2b9167db40a)

Comment: Thank you @ikegami. Much much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CryptoJS, v4.1.1 uses SHA1 as PBKDF2 digest by default, CryptoJS, v4.2.0 uses SHA256 by default. In order for SHA256 to be used in the Perl code, you must add `hash_class => 'HMACSHA2'`, i.e.:

```perl
my $pbkdf2 = Crypt::PBKDF2->new(output_len=>128/8, iterations=>1000, hash_class => 'HMACSHA2');
```

For completeness: In CryptoJS the digest can also be set explicitly with the `hasher` option: The following code would also use SHA256 as PBKDF2 digest under v4.1.1:

```js
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {keySize: 128/32, iterations: 1000, hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256});
```

Note that CryptoJS has recently been [discontinued](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#discontinued) and is no longer maintained.

Comment: In addition to this fix, the OP might want to increase the number of iterations to the now-default 250,000.

Comment: @ikegami - The OP should set the iteration count as high as possible while maintaining acceptable performance.